# Re-importing an exported quality profile seems to lose rules

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm trying to set up a Dockered Sonarqube with a custom quality profile for use on developer machines. There is already a central server, but it's a very old release, and we would like to have developers have a local instance to check their code against while working in a branch (the central sonar is only looking at Git master so mistakes would only show up after a merge). The overall plan is to have a GoCD pipeline which on a commit on the rules XML pick them up and build a fresh Docker image for local use.

Steps taken so far:

- Log on to the old (3.6.1) Sonarqube and export the rules
- Start a clean Sonarqube docker (sonarqube:5.1) and import the rules
- Now there are lots of deprecated rules, so go over them and replace with the new ones. This also gets rid of some duplications, which is nice.

Now for the strange part / question: after doing the above I'm left with a 5.1 sonarqube quality profile containing 211 rules. When I export these and grep on '<rule>' there are 211 tags, so looks like they're all there.
Yet when I start another clean sonarqube:5.1 image and use a curl POST to re-import the xml I just created, I only see 106 rules reported in the console; exporting them leaves me with a file containing 106 '<rule>' tags.

I'm not sure yet but a quick diff of the two exported XML files look like showing the checkstyle and pmd repositoryKeys might be missing.

If anybody has any pointers as to what is going on here they would be very welcome, as I'm a bit stumped at this point (and I'm so close...)

Answer (score 1):

First, you might consider [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/), which offers developers on-the-fly checking in 3 IDE's without connecting to a server (so it works just fine on branches)!

But it runs with a default profile, so if that doesn't do it for you:

SonarQube is no longer shipped with the CheckStyle and PMD plugins by default, so that's why those rules are missing.

The vast majority of CheckStyle and PMD rules have been replaced anyway in newer versions of the Java plugin, so what I'd suggest is this:

- Spin up a fresh 5.1
- Install Checkstyle & PMD plugins
- Import the profile from your 3.6 server
- Use the interface to replace the deprecated ChechStyle & PMD rules with their Java plugin replacements
- Decide you can live without the unreplaced remainder ;)
- Export the updated profile and use *it* to seed your Docker image

Comment: Thank you for the update. Based on what you wrote I ended up modifying the Docker build environment and Dockerfile so that it adds the plugins to the image before uploading the rules. This way everything I exported is still there in the new image.